# Redis does not load AOF on startup

Tags: redis

I recently configured Redis to use AOF as well as RDB snapshotting.

However, it does not look like the AOF is replayed correctly on server startup.

I stopped the service. Then I made sure `/var/redis/appendonly.aof` is valid using `redis-check-aof`.

Then I started the server again. In this moment, the RDB file was empty. That's another issue I need to look into - Redis started losing all the data from time to time.

In the log file I can see the AOF is supposed to be loaded correctly:

`DB loaded from append only file: 1.474 seconds`

However, when I try to read a value which I know should be there, I get nothing:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get iQube:Live:wordCount:2015:11:13:10:6
(nil)
```

In the AOF though, there are commands like this:

```
INCRBY
$36
iQube:Live:wordCount:2015:11:13:10:6
$1
2
*2
$4
```

Is there something else I need to do to make this work?

Comment: What Redis version are you using ? Do you have `save` commands in the `redis.conf` ?

Comment: I am using 3.0.5. In config I have the (I believe) default values: `save 900 1`, `save 300 10` and `save 60 10000`

Comment: List the keys after a service restart.  Are there any ?

Comment: There are some. Lot of them is missing, though.

Comment: Try a simple test: set a key immediately before restarting the service, and check if the key appears then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault. I did not secure the server properly and became target of probably the [most typical attack to Redis](http://antirez.com/news/96). In effect, the AOF file contained `flushall` commands which wiped the DB clean upon loading.

At the very least, I recommend putting these three lines to `redis.conf`:

```
rename-command CONFIG someverylongandveryunguessablestring
rename-command FLUSHDB ""
rename-command FLUSHALL ""
```